# What does the "w" in "yum install -y php56w" stand for?

Tags: linux, php, yum, rpm

Following instruction on [this page](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/php-centos.html)  I installed PHP using command:

`yum install -y php56w`

My question is: what does the 'w' stand for in php56w?

Answer (score 7):

The tutorial has you download PHP from a third party repository named [webtatic](https://webtatic.com).

The operator of this repro has compiled the source tarballs of various versions of PHP that are not in the official CentOS repository.

Presumably the 'w' stands for 'webtatic', to differentiate these packages from the official CentOS ones.

Comment: Use standard repositories if you can and avoid third party repos, unless you have a compelling reason and have reason to trust the thirdparty maintainer not only not to be malicious, but also technically competent and reliable in the sense the the repo gets updates in case of security problems.

Comment: If that howto tells you to use a thirdparty repo for software that is also in your distribution it should state a reason for doing so. Read howto and forum tips with a critical eye.

Comment: Didn't realize that I was installing a package made by third party.  What is a command to install official php package?